# Select input surrounded by multiple divs

Tags: jquery, input

Is there a way to select only the first input value?

```
<div class="whatever1">
        <div class="whatever2">
    <input type="text" id="whateverID" >
    </div>
</div>  

<div class="foo">
    <div class="whatever2">
    <input type="text" id="whateverID">
    </div>  
</div>
```

I cannot change ID, class, name of any div or input. How can I get to the first input?

This did not work

```
$('whateverID').first()
```

Comment: I got different required messages if this helps

Comment: Your markup is invalid. **id attributes should be unique in a HTML page** you should really look into changing the markup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I see you are using the same ID multiple times that is not valid. You can use the id only once on page.

And to select the id you need to give the `#` before id name.

And you can select the first input type by this code:

```
$("input[type=text]").first();
```

Or can use:

```
$("input[type=text]").eq(0);
```

OR

```
$("input[type=text]:eq(0)");
```

Choose which you want to use.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the same ID for two elements. Try to select them with a class.

More general: use `$('#id')` to select by ID, use `$('.class')` to select by class in jQuery.

If this is the first input on your page, you can try `$('input[type="text"]').eq(0)` to select it.

Answer (score 0):

There has to be never more than one id on a page..
use this to get ur div selected.

```
$('#whateverID');
```

Returns the HTML-Object.

```
$('#whateverID').val();
```

Returns the value of your input-field.

Comment: Id is generic and it is a dirty workaround but I think I have to change the ID then

thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
$('#whateverID:first').val();
```